# Python 3.5 "for loop" "enumerate()” Select Word from List

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, enumerate

Hi I'm new here I've just started learning python

Individual words in wordList will be referred to as “word” as a variable.

who would I set this up this for a python english grammar gen program by the way.

also I wanna try  to Enter a loop that repeats once for each word in wordList. Trying to use a for loop with “enumerate()” function but I keep getting stuck. Any help would be great.

```
print('Welcome to my English Test App')



# Import the random module to allow us to select the word list and questions at random.
import random
candidateWords = ['HELLO', 'GOODBYE', 'NAME', 'DAY', 'NIGHT', 'HOUR', 'POTATO', 'BIG', 'SMALL', 'GOOD', 'BAD', 'YES', 'NO', 'HOUSE', 'QUESTION', 'BALLOON', 'CAT', 'DUCK', 'PIGEON', 'POSTER', 'TELEVISION', 'SPY', 'RHYTHM', 'SUBSTANTIAL', 'SNOW', 'MAGNET', 'TOWEL', 'WALKING', 'SPEAKER', 'UNCHARACTERISTICALLY']
# places words down in a list
s = random.sample (candidateWords, 5)
for index,w in enumerate(s):
print(index,w)
```

Comment: Actually your question is unclear, What is your expected output. ?

Comment: I'm at the moment trying to get 5 words from the list. Trying Individual words in wordList to be referred to as “word”. and to use a emutrate loop to display the words question1/5:   ,question 2/5: ect

Comment: The next line `(random.sample (candidateWords, 5))` will give right ?

Comment: yeah that is to just cut down the number of words in the list as we only want 5 for now we then need to get those words in a list using the enumerate loop,

Comment: There is neither a loop nor enumerate in your code?

Comment: Please add some output sample you want.

Comment: yeah I know I have been trying to get the output from the random.sample to go into a loop but I keep running into problems.

Comment: Please add manually.

Comment: added, All I need to dow to get the index to display as one higherthen what it normally is so no 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your question is how to use enumerate, here's an application for your code sample:

```
import random
candidateWords = ['HELLO', 'GOODBYE', 'NAME', 'DAY', 'NIGHT', 'HOUR', 'POTATO', 'BIG', 'SMALL', 'GOOD', 'BAD', 'YES', 'NO', 'HOUSE', 'QUESTION', 'BALLOON', 'CAT', 'DUCK', 'PIGEON', 'POSTER', 'TELEVISION', 'SPY', 'RHYTHM', 'SUBSTANTIAL', 'SNOW', 'MAGNET', 'TOWEL', 'WALKING', 'SPEAKER', 'UNCHARACTERISTICALLY']

s = random.sample (candidateWords, 5)

# loop through the list using enumerate

for index,w in enumerate(s):
    print("word {} out of {} is {}, nb vowels is {}".format(index+1,len(s),w,countVowels(w)))
```

output

```
word 1 out of 5 is NIGHT, nb vowels is 1
word 2 out of 5 is BALLOON, nb vowels is 3
word 3 out of 5 is SUBSTANTIAL, nb vowels is 4
word 4 out of 5 is BIG, nb vowels is 1
word 5 out of 5 is PIGEON, nb vowels is 3
```

Note that you don't have to use enumerate if you don't need the indexes:

```
for w in s:
    print(w,countVowels(w))
```

for your count vowels (since everyone seemed to think this was the question at some point), you can do this, and whether Y is a vowel or not is up to you since it's unclear ([Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/words/is-the-letter-y-a-vowel-or-a-consonant))

```
def countVowels(word):
    return sum(word.count(x) for x in "AEIOUY")
```

The generator comp will apply count characters for each vowels in the word, then applies standard sum function.

Answer (score 0):

```
print('Welcome to my English Test App')

#Import the random module to allow us to select the word list and questions at random.

import random

candidateWords = ['HELLO', 'GOODBYE', 'NAME', 'DAY', 'NIGHT', 'HOUR', 'POTATO', 'BIG', 'SMALL', 'GOOD', 'BAD', 'YES', 'NO', 'HOUSE', 'QUESTION', 'BALLOON', 'CAT', 'DUCK', 'PIGEON', 'POSTER', 'TELEVISION', 'SPY', 'RHYTHM', 'SUBSTANTIAL', 'SNOW', 'MAGNET', 'TOWEL', 'WALKING', 'SPEAKER', 'UNCHARACTERISTICALLY']

# places words down in a list
s = random.sample (candidateWords, 5)
for index,w in enumerate(s):
    print(index,w)   #your code have indent problem
```